# How to install apk Samsung Galaxy Gear S through Android Studio?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to run may sample application of wear in Samsung Galaxy Gear S. But I am getting device not connected. Also, I have enabled usb debugging. So anyone know how to run sample application in Samsung Galaxy Gear S through Android studio?

Answer (score 0):

- If you're on Windows, make sure you've installed the ADB drivers through Device Manager.
- If you're on Linux, make sure you've configured your udev rules by following the setup guide on the Android Developer site

  http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up

  Generally, this means creating a file at /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules with a line like the following:

  > SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

  You can get the vendor id by running `lsusb`. Also, make sure you're in the `plugdev` group.
- If neither of those apply (and since you said you've already enabled USB debugging on the device), check to make sure that your USB cable and the charging cradle are mechanically sound.
- Failing all that, open up the Android Wear app on your phone and enable Bluetooth Debugging. Here are the steps to enable it:

  > **Enable USB debugging on the handheld:**
  >
  > - Open the Settings app and scroll to the bottom.
  > - If it doesn't have a Developer Options setting, tap About Phone (or About Tablet), scroll to the bottom, and tap the build number 7 times.
  > - Go back and tap Developer Options.
  > - Enable USB debugging.

  You'll then be able to use ADB-over-IP to connect to the Android Wear device, using your phone as a proxy. Make sure you have your phone connected via USB and that you have USB debugging enabled, of source. Instructions:

  > **Set Up a Debugging Session**
  >
  > 1. On the handheld, open the Android Wear companion app.
  > 2. Tap the menu on the top right and select Settings.
  > 3. Enable Debugging over Bluetooth. You should see a tiny status summary appear under the option:
  >
  >    ```
  >    Host: disconnected
  >    Target: connected
  >    ```
  >
  > Connect the handheld to your machine over USB and run:
  >
  > ```
  > adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub
  > adb connect localhost:4444
  > ```
  >
  > Note: You can use any available port that you have access to.
  >   In the Android Wear companion app, you should see the status change to:
  >
  > ```
  > Host: connected
  > Target: connected
  > ```
  >
  > **Debug Your App**
  >   Your wearable should show up as localhost:4444 when running adb devices. To run any adb command, use this format:
  >   adb -s localhost:4444  
  >   If there are no other devices connected over TCP/IP (namely emulators), you can shorten the command to:
  >
  > adb -e 
  >   For example:
  >
  > adb -e logcat
  >   adb -e shell
  >   adb -e bugreport

  Source: [Android Developers - Debugging over Bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html#SetupDevices)

Comment: When I am going to connect Samsung Galaxy Gear S through Android Wear companion app, It's just displaying "connecting to your watch..." nothing happen.

Comment: Make sure bluetooth is enabled. Failing that, you may need to call support. That's basic functionality of the watch.

Comment: Bluetooth is enabled because when I am trying to connecting with samsung gear app and it's working. problem with only Android wear app

Comment: Gear S is not an Android Wear device. It runs Tizen OS, not Android.